# Children's book: "Augmenter" is a key concept

Tags: identification-request

I read this book about 5 years ago (2017), in my fourth grade Southern California classroom (aged 9 to 10). I remember the word “Augmenter” being what the story was mainly about. I think some people were Augmenters.

I don’t remember whether it was hardcover or paperback. It couldn’t have been more than 300 pages, unless I misremember another book. It was written in English.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature SE. Please take the [Tour] when you get chance, it will tell you how to get the best out of the site. Can you give us *any* more information? Do you mean there was something *called* an augmenter in the book, which was important or that the word 'augmenter' itself was significant? Can you remember *anything* about the story? One word isn't much to go on. When I search for children's novels with 'augmenter', a lot of the results I get are in French - you seem to mention the possibility of it not being in English, what other language might it have been?

Comment: @Spagirl Certain people were called “Augmenters” I believe

Comment: @polyumbrial So the keyword was "actuator" rather than "augmentor" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else who may be looking for this book, its name is *[The Quantum League: Spell Robbers](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18114551-spell-robbers)*

> After Ben Warner is recruited to join a “science camp” led by the eccentric quantum physicist Dr. Madeleine Hughes, he quickly realizes it’s no regular science camp. Along with his new friend, Peter, Ben discovers the secret, powerful art of Actuation—the ability to change reality by simply imagining it differently.
>
> When a mysterious group of men invade Dr. Hughes’s laboratory, abducting her and stealing her precious equipment, Ben and Peter are suddenly caught up in a turf war between dangerous actuators desperate for Dr. Hughes’s innovative technology. And as Ben and Peter are pulled into a perilous, hidden world full of impossibilities now made possible, will their combined powers be enough to save Dr. Hughes and vanquish their enemies before it’s too late?

[This review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/2081329499) mentions the "augmenter":

> My name is Ben. You're an NA, so I won't try to fully explain what it means to be an actuator. I can make things happen with my mind; it's quantum physics, not magic. I've been recruited by the Quantum League, but I'm furious that they've detached me from my mom. She doesn't remember anything about me! Mr. Weathersky says they'll reattach her if I'll complete one mission. The Dread Cloaks have stolen a portable augmenter and have kidnapped Dr. Hughes to perfect it. This machine will become a powerful weapon in the wrong hands, and the leader of the Dread Cloaks is that man. The League says they'll return Ronin's daughter if he'll help me with my mission. I don't know if I can trust this criminal, and I don't know if I can trust the League either. They want me to convince the Dread Cloaks that I'm willing to become a double agent, but I don't know how to do it. Ronin tells me to improvise, so I guess that's what I'll do.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/13683)

Comment: You can also self-accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Could this be Madeline Dyer's *[Untamed](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25537679-untamed)*, published in 2016?

[image: Front cover of Untamed]

Bolding is done by me

> As one of the last Untamed humans left in the world, Seven’s life has always been controlled by tight rules. Stay away from the Enhanced. Don’t question your leader. And, most importantly, never switch sides--because once you’re Enhanced there’s no going back. Even if you have become the perfect human being.
>
> But after a disastrous raid on an Enhanced city, Seven soon finds herself in her enemy’s power. Realizing it’s only a matter of time before she too develops a taste for the chemical **augmenters** responsible for the erosion of humanity, Seven knows she must act quickly if she’s to escape and save her family from the same fate.
>
> Yet, as one of the most powerful Seers that the Untamed and Enhanced have ever known, Seven quickly discovers that she alone holds the key to the survival of only one race. But things aren’t clear-cut anymore, and with Seven now questioning the very beliefs she was raised on, she knows she has an important choice to make. One that has two very different outcomes.
>
> Seven must choose wisely whose side she joins, for the War of Humanity is underway, and Death never takes kindly to traitors.

Found via a search for `site:goodreads.com "called augmenters"`, which led me to [this review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1420278727?book_show_action=true).

Comment: The book wasn’t a dystopian writing, and it wasn’t chemical augmenters but rather people who were augmenters

Comment: @polyumbrial :) That sounds like good details to edit into your question.